# Asymptotic normality of Kernel Density Estimator

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, asymptotics

## Set up

We consider kernel density estimation.
$X_1, \ldots, X_n \overset{\mathrm{i.i.d.}}{\sim} F$(c.d.f., unknown).

$F$ has a density $f$ and then the object it wants to estimate pointwise.

Kernel Density Estimator:
$$
\hat{f_n} := \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{h}K \left(\frac{y-X_j}{h} \right).
$$
$h$ means bandwidth.

## What I know

If $h$ satisfied $h \to 0, nh \to \infty$, then
\begin{align}
\mathrm{bias\ of\ }\hat{f_n}(y) &= \frac{1}{2}h^2 f''(y)\tau^2 + o(h^2),\\
\mathrm{Var}[\hat{f_n}(y)] &= \frac{1}{nh}f(y) \int K^2(y)dy + o(\frac{1}{nh}),
\end{align}
where
$$
\tau^2 := \int y^2 K(y)dy.
$$

## Question

Why do the following limitation hold?
$$
\frac{\mathrm{bias\ of\ }\hat{f_n}(y)}{\sqrt{\mathrm{Var}[\hat{f_n}(y)]}}\to \xi,
$$
where $\xi$ is a constant.